# Faster alternatives for calcOpticalFlowSF

Tags: performance, opencv, opticalflow

Is there any faster alternatives for calcOpticalFlowSF? Its just sooo slow and wanna run this thing with a sequence of frames coming from a video. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There several methods for optical flow based motion estimation but you have to consider several things:

- are you restricted to CPU implementation / GPU's implementation could decrease drastically the run-time
- do you need dense motion fields or just a set of sparse motion vectors / sparse OF methods are more scalable and thus need less run-time
- accuracy / the very high accuracy of dense methods is most only critical on motion boundaries. In many application you could approximate a dense motion field by a grid of sparse motion vectors and thus can use sparse methods as the pyramidal Lucas Kanade (OpenCV)

current libaries / methods are:

Dense Methods:

- OpenCV 2.4.4 provides on GPU BroxOpticalFlow that is fast too
- the [FlowLib](http://gpu4vision.icg.tugraz.at/index.php?content=subsites/flowlib/flowlib.php) of the GPU4Vision Group provides a high accurate GPU implementation
- GPU implementation of the [TV-L1](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/chzach/opensource.html) on GPU is provided by

Sparse Methods:

- OpenCV since 2.4.2 provides the pyramidal Lucas Kanade on GPU /earlier verions also very fast implementation on the CPU
- the [RLOFLib](http://www.nue.tu-berlin.de/menue/forschung/projekte/rlof/) provides an more accurate implementation for GPU / CPU and Matlab
- the [Gain Adaptive Lucas Kanade / KLT](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/chzach/opensource.html) is also available for GPU

You could also take a look to the current Optical Flow benchmarks, where the researcher sometimes provides Link. Common Optical Flow benchmarks are the [Middlebury](http://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/) and the [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=flow&error=3&eval=est)